# PHP, MySQL input data

Tags: php, mysql

I create some table(in MySQL):

```
create table clients
( clientid int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  Name char(50) not null,
  SecondName char(50) not null,
  address char(100) not null,
  City char(30) not null
  Email char(100);
```

I want to input  datas(Name,SecondName,address,City,Email) into my database NewClientBase from webpage by filling by customer his personal data, but clientid should be generated by program:

```
<html>   
<?php    
...
  // short names initialization. Taken from filling external form
  $Name=$_POST['Name'];    
  $SecondName=$_POST['SecondName'];    
  $Address=$_POST['Address'];    
  $City=$_POST['City'];    
  $Email=$_POST['Email'];    
 $clientid=0;    

  if (!$Name || !$SecondName || !$Address || !$City || !$Email) {    
     echo "Not all data completed.<br />"
          ."Return and try again";
     exit;
  }    

  if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {    
    $Name = addslashes($Name);    
    $SecondName = addslashes($SecondName);    
    $Address = addslashes($Address);    
    $City = addslashes($City);    
    $Email = doubleval($Email);    
  }    
  @ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '********', 'NewClientBase');    

$wynik_sprawdzania= mysqli_query($db, $sprawdzanie);    
$ile_znalezionych=$wynik_sprawdzania->fetch_row();     
$ilosc_pol=$wynik_sprawdzania->field_count;    
.....     
      // a new record with the next number is calculated:

    $clientid=$wynik_sprawdzania->fetch_row()+1;    
....    
and created a new record with this number:        
$zapytanie = "insert into clients values        ('".$clientid."','".$Name."','".$SecondName."', '".$Address."','".$City."',     '".$Email."')";    
  $wynik = $db->query($zapytanie);    
 .....    
 $db->close();     
?>    
</html>
```

the problem is:
 if  (for example) 5th record is generated and input into database like this

```
$zapytanie = "insert into clients values (5,'".$Name."','".$SecondName."',     '".$Address."','".$City."', '".$Email."')";    
  $wynik = $db->query($zapytanie);
```

all record is inserted into database correctly.
but if it is inserted like this

```
$zapytanie = "insert into clients values     
('".$clientid."','".$Name."','".$SecondName."', '".$Address."','".$City."',     '".$Email."')";    
  $wynik = $db->query($zapytanie);
```

($clientid No 5 is calculated programly as shown above) record is not created.     Neither '".clientid."' nor '.$clientid.' Can anybody help me? Any solution     exists? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ClientId is defined as Int, not as string. You try to input string. Remove the single quotes on $clientid.

```
$zapytanie = "insert into clients values     
(".$clientid.",'".$Name."','".$SecondName."', '".$Address."','".$City."',     '".$Email."')";    
  $wynik = $db->query($zapytanie);
```

Comment: Ok, and what is the solution?

Comment: The solution is the source line i have writen above. The single quotes around the variable make a string insert. Wirhout it is a number.

Answer (score 0):

The variable $clientid should be considered as integer and should not add any quotes.

```
$zapytanie = "insert into clients values     
(".$clientid.",'".$Name."','".$SecondName."', '".$Address."','".$City."',     '".$Email."')";    
  $wynik = $db->query($zapytanie);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hy! Everything works but in a strang way. This is my program: